# How to solve $ \frac{x-1}{x-c} < \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: inequality, parametric

I have this inequality:

$$\frac{x-1}{x-c} < \frac{1}{2}     \quad c \in \mathbb{R}$$

can someone show me how to do it?

EDIT: Your answers are what I did, I studied the two cases  and got:

$$x < 2 - c  \quad \quad \quad for\quad x > c$$

and

$$x > 2 - c \quad \quad \quad for \quad x< c$$

But my book solution says:

$$[S = {\quad x < c ∨ x > 1 \quad for\quad c ≤ 1;\quad  x < 1 ∨ x > c\quad for\quad c > 1}]$$

Comment: Is something known of $c$? Is x and c elements of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What do you know about $c$?

Comment: Ok I've inserted c \in R.

Comment: What do we always do with fractions when we compare, add or substract them ? ... Put them ....

Comment: The solution in your book is not correct. If $c = 2 > 1$, then $x = 3 > c$ is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**: Here's a simpler way.

Let
$$
f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x-c}-\frac12 = \frac{x-(2-c)}{2(x-c)}
.
$$
We would like to know when $\color{blue}{f(x)<0}$.

Make a table of the signs of the factors $x-(2-c)$ and $2(x-c)$; they change their signs when $x=2-c$ and when $x=c$, and when we write out the table we need to know which one of the numbers $c$ and $2-c$ to put on the left and which one to put on the right. So we have to split into cases. Obviously, $c<2-c$ if and only if $c<1$.

First case, $c<1$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
x & &c& &2-c& \\[0.3ex]
\hline
x-(2-c) & - && - &0& + \\
2(x-c) & - &0& + && + \\
\hline
f(x) & + &\text{undef.}& - &0& + 
\end{array}
$$
Looking where the minus sign in the last line is, we find that $f(x)<0 \iff \color{blue}{c < x < 2-c}$ in this case.

Second case, $c>1$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
x & &2-c& &c& \\[0.3ex]
\hline
x-(2-c) & - &0& + && + \\
2(x-c) & - && - &0& + \\
\hline
f(x) & + &0& - &\text{undef.}& + 
\end{array}
$$
Hence $f(x)<0 \iff \color{blue}{2-c < x < c}$ in this case.

Third case, $c=1$: Here $f(x)=1/2$ identically, hence we never have $f(x)<0$, so there are no solutions in this case.

**Original answer**:
To simplify, let $y=x-1$ and $d=c-1$:
$$
\frac{x-1}{x-c} < \frac{1}{2}
\iff
\frac{y}{y-d} < \frac{1}{2} 
\iff
1 + \frac{d}{y-d} < \frac{1}{2} 
\iff
\frac{d}{y-d} < -\frac{1}{2} 
.
$$
Now if $d=0$ (i.e., if $c=1$), this is false for all $y$.
So we can assume $d \neq 0$ and write
$$
\dots \iff
\frac{1}{\frac{y}{d}-1} < -\frac{1}{2}
\iff
\frac{1}{z-1} < -\frac{1}{2}
,
$$
where $z = \frac{y}{d}$.
Solve this inequality in what ever way you prefer (most easily by just looking at the graph of $1/(z-1)$); you get $-1<z<1$, i.e.,
$$
\left| \frac{y}{d} \right|<1
\iff
\frac{|y|}{|d|}<1
\iff
|y|<|d|
$$
(using in the last step that $|d|$ is positive).

Now split into cases: if $d>0$ you get $|y|<d$, and if $d<0$ you get $|y|<-d$.

In terms of the original quantities:

- If $c>1$ then $|x-1|<c-1$, which gives $-(c-1)<x-1<c-1$, i.e.,
  $$
  2-c<x<c
  .
  $$
- If $c<1$, then $|x-1|<1-c$, which gives $-(1-c)<x-1<1-c$,
  i.e.,
  $$
  c < x < 2-c
  .
  $$
- If $c=1$, there are no solutions.

Comment: Ok, so It took me a while to understand your demonstration but I finally got it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! I added another method too, which is probably easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $2(x-1)<x-c$ for  $x-c>0$. Then the other case.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know when
$\dfrac{x-1}{x-c} < \dfrac{1}{2}     \quad c \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $x=c$,
the left side is not defined,
so we can assume that
$x \ne c$.

If $c=1$,
this is always false.

Since
$\dfrac{x-1}{x-c}
=\dfrac{x-c+c-1}{x-c}
=1+\dfrac{c-1}{x-c}
$,
this is equivalent to
$1+\dfrac{c-1}{x-c}
\lt \dfrac12
$ or
$\dfrac{1-c}{x-c}
\gt \dfrac12
$.

If
$c <1$,
we must have
$x > c$,
so we can clear the fraction
and get
$2-2c > x-c$
or
$x < 2-c$.

If
$c > 1$
we must have
$x < c$
so we can rewrite this as
$\dfrac{c-1}{c-x} 
\gt \dfrac12$.
Clearing the fraction,
we get
$2c-2 > c-x$
or
$x > 2-c$.